# Force user to fill in at least text area or file

Tags: 6, forms

A registered user is creating a node with a body and file field. I want to force the user to either fill the body with 300 chars or select a file. At least one needs to be selected/filled.

How can I do it?
Can I do this using the Rules module?

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you interested in?

Comment: Drupal 6.2 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you could achieve this with rules. You could however create a small custom module that adds a form validation function to the node edit form. The validator would check that the appropriate conditions are met.

**Edit:** something like this would work I think for content type *page*.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter for page_node_form.
 *
 * @see module_validate
 */
function module_form_page_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'module_validate';
}

/**
 * Form validator for page_node_form.
 */
function module_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // This strips HTML tags - to disable, remove the filter_xss() call.
  $body_length = drupal_strlen(filter_xss($form_state['values']['body'], array()));

  // We're assuming the field is called 'file' and we're checking the first file.
  $file = $form_state['values']['field_file'][0];

  // Rather than checking against 300, we should perhaps call node_get_types()
  // and find the configured word limit.
  if (body_length < 300 && !$file['fid']) {
    form_set_error('body', t('Please ensure that you either enter 300 characters into the body field, or upload a file.'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you pl. give me sample code?

Comment: @AgA I've updated my answer with a snippet

Comment: @AgA er, what, where?!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the Rules module can be used for validation.  There may be modules out there to allow you do some custom validation but for your particular case, you may want to write your own, small validation module using [`hook_node_validate`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7)

Comment: It'd be nice if you can give a sample text which I can copy paste to create a module.

Comment: If you go ahead and try it, you can feel free to paste the code in there and I will help you refine it if you need further assistance.  The function documentation as linked above has an example of how to use it.